# how to get DNS server in c-ares

Tags: c++, c, asynchronous, dns, c-ares

I'm using [c-ares-1.10.0](http://c-ares.haxx.se/ares_send.html)
which is a C library for asynchronous DNS requests ,it's a good lib to do name resolves~
Now I have a question when I use c-ares~

there is multi nameserver in "/etc/resolv.conf" 
such as 
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 2.2.2.2

I want to get Dns server which c-ares used to do dns query,1.1.1.1 or 2.2.2.2，
But I can't find the API in c-ares docs~
Does any one know how to get dns server?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function from ares.h:

```
CARES_EXTERN int ares_get_servers(ares_channel channel,
                                  struct ares_addr_node **servers);
```

The servers can also be retrieved with the

```
  int ares_save_options(ares_channel channel, struct ares_options *options, int *optmask))
```

function , as members of `struct ares_option`, though I believe that can only contain IPv4 server addresses, while ares_get_servers() can provide you with both IPv4/IPv6 servers.

Comment: Ths,but function "ares_get_servers" get all servers,I want to get  nameserver which "c-ares" make query when I call ares_gethostbyname

Comment: @user3282867 ok. That info isn't available to you.